# How to add default text to a dropdown in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

I am trying to add the "--select--" text to a dropdown, but I am not getting the proper way to do it.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("dd_searchFor", new SelectList(ClientSystem.Dropdown.DDSearchFor(), "Value", "Text"), "--select--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "height:10px;" })
```

when I do this, the "--select--" text does not appear within the dropdown but it appears as the first element of the drop down list.

Comment: Its supposed to be the first option. What are you wanting to do? Where do you want it to appear?

Comment: You used style = "height:10px;" and the selection part doesn't seem like that. If you change it for example height:40px, you can see it. Did you mean that or you want "--select--" to use like a placeholder?

Comment: @kkakkurt yes got it now, but it appears as the placeholder as well as an item in the dropdown. I want it to appear only as a placeholder text

Comment: On single selects, the first element is assumed to be selected by the browser automatically. You can do it with some javascript libraries, for example: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/